# ISBLANK displaying 0 for an empty timed format linked cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an ISBLANK function being used on a cell that contains a minute and second format (MM:SS).

Even though the linked cells are blank in the range C7:C16, the ISBLANK value returns 0 when it should be blank. The latter part of the formula calculation that shows seconds may perhaps be interfering with the ISBLANK formula.

Here is the Google Sheet, you can make a copy at File-Make a copy

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V-nL8S4M7B54ZLUl2FTWCxaJMlAz-LF2nY_HoxNYji4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the cell not empty, it has formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tl;Dr: Remove `""`

---

Current formulas

B7

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A7),"",LEN(A7)/18.2/86400)
```

C7

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B7),"",(((HOUR(B7))*60+(MINUTE(B7)))*60 +SECOND(B7)))
```

Resulting formulas

B7

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A7),,LEN(A7)/18.2/86400)
```

C7

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B7),,(((HOUR(B7))*60+(MINUTE(B7)))*60 +SECOND(B7)))
```

Comment: Hi Ruben, The value 0 still remains in Column C using this revised function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that any of the `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND` functions will default to `0`. eg.`=HOUR("")`

An alternative is to **use `ISNUMBER`** instead. You could also wrap your formulas in an `ArrayFormula`.

For column `B` please try the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",LEN(A2:A)/18.2/86400))
```

In column `C` try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B),(((HOUR(B2:B))*60+(MINUTE(B2:B)))*60 +SECOND(B2:B)),))
```